# Spring custom AuthenticationProvider for Principal with additional data

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm fairly new to Spring.

My goal is to have some `AuthenticationProvider` with a custom `authenticate` Method that takes an `Authenticate` object as argument with more than just a user name and password. Let's say a realm name (and there can be 2 users with the same user name when they are in different realms). I already looked for answers to my question, but the simple answers to questions about authentication only explain how to extend `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`, which doesn't cater my needs because the retrieve method only takes a user name as argument while I need the realm name as well to retrieve the user. The complex ones are about extending or implementing all kinds of different Spring classes and interfaces without the context being explained.

So the simple question is:

How do I have to implement / extend an `AuthenticationProvider` to be able to read custom data out of an `Authentication` object?

My call would look like this (yes, I want to get an OAuth2 token):

```
curl -vX POST http://localhost:9001/oauth/token \
-d "client_id=myId&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&username=myUser&password=1234&realm=realm3"
```

Notice the `realm=realm3` at the end.

The call without the extra data and with my own sub class of `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` already works when there's just one realm.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I have to implement / extend an AuthenticationProvider to be
>   able to read custom data out of an Authentication object?

**RealmAuthenticationProvider**

```
public class RealmAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private RUPAuthenticator rupAuthenticator;

    public RealmAuthenticationProvider(RUPAuthenticator rupAuthenticator) {
        this.rupAuthenticator = rupAuthenticator;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        Object credentials = authentication.getCredentials();
        Object realm = authentication.getDetails();
        if (rupAuthenticator.authenticate(principal, credentials, realm)) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")); //use any GrantedAuthorities you need
            return new RealmAuthenticationToken(principal, credentials, realm, grantedAuths);
        };
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return RealmAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

**RealmAuthenticationToken**

```
public class RealmAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {

    private Object realm;

    public RealmAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials, Object realm, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(principal,credentials, authorities);
        this.realm = realm;
    }
}
```

**RUPAuthenticator**

```
public interface RUPAuthenticator {
    boolean authenticate(Object username, Object password, Object realm);
}
```

**You would just have to provide an implementation for RUPAuthenticator that states whether the username, password, realm combinations are correct.**

And then register the custom AuthenticationProvider (RealmAuthenticationProvider) as a bean. 
Below is an example of an authentication provider that accepts requests from a specific user:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        List<AuthenticationProvider> providers = new ArrayList<AuthenticationProvider>();
        providers.add(new RealmAuthenticationProvider(new RUPAuthenticator() {
            @Override
            public boolean authenticate(Object username, Object password, Object realm) {
                return (username.equals("sa") && password.equals("sa") && realm.equals("realm2"));
            }
        }));
        return new ProviderManager(providers);
    }
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That looks very promising, I'll mark it as answer already, although I still have to figure out how the classes relate to each other, the sequence of calls and what to change in the security.xml first to make this work.

Comment: I wasn't able to integrate it yet. Don't I need to mention a UserDetailsService to the <authentication-manager> in the security.xml? And the UserDetailsService has loadUserByUsername(String username) and assumes a username is unique.

Comment: You don't need a UserDetails service as you aren't using an AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider instance. You need to register a ProviderManager that includes the RealmAuthenticationProvider, which in turn needs a RUPAuthenticator that does the actual authorizatoin, based on the example I gave

Comment: The problem is that in addition to the user+realm authentication I also need the normal authentication. In my security.xml I have set up a clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter that uses a clientAuthenticationManager that uses a clientDetailsUserService. Then there's another authenticationManager that uses a normalUserAuthenticationProvider. One of the managers has an ID, the other an alias, both get mentioned in the filter (one in the name, one in the ref of a property element). I'm confused.

Comment: Will get back to you sometime tomorrow and see what we can figure out. The idea is that you can combine the authentication providers in an authentication manager. In the case of ProviderManager however, if one of the AuthenticationProviders succesfully authenticates, then the rest arent taken into consideration. I have to see in what way we can combine the two authentication providers

Comment: In the AuthProvider for the normal users (without realm) I can just check if there's a realm in the authentication.getDetails(), and vice versa for the other provider. This would ensure that only the correct providers successfully authenticate the according users.

Comment: I got a bit further: The AuthenticationProviders get chosen by the Token they support. The new RealmAuthenticationProvider supports the new RealmAuthenticationToken. But when the CompositeTokenGranter (called by the TokenEndpoint) picks the ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter, this granter creates a UserPasswordAuthenticationToken, so the correct AuthenticationProvider can't get chosen (not supported). I guess I'll need to implement my own TokenGranter? This seems to be more related to OAuth2 then I thought at the beginning.